# Can anyone please identify the flowers around this cake?

Tags: identification

I apologise that my first question is asking for identification!

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: They look like fake flowers - are they?

Comment: @Bamboo I honestly don't know - we're trying to find something similar for our wedding cake. If they are fake and without a real-life name I will accept defeat...

Comment: Lyall, welcome! Note that identification questions are perfectly acceptable here (although we usually do ids for real plants). I will not mod-close this question as it’s actually answerable, but the community may disagree.

Comment: @Stephie Thank you, and thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are artificial flowers, sorry. (Or not, if your baker can reproduce them.)

They seem to be modeled based on dogwoods (four whiteish petals with a green tinge, green center), but dogwoods blooms are significantly larger and don’t grow as a vine.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely dogwood, I believe. It's hard to see the centers.

Comment: That does look very close! Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't concerned about them being artificial, I just wanted to identify the genera! And there are species of dogwood with smaller blossoms that have narrow branches with curly ends that seem to "vine."

Comment: @jesset: often there are no genera on artificial flowers. Often we see mixing characters (Dianthus like, but with 6 or 7 petals are frequent on artificial flowers). You may be more luckly because this flowers have just 4 petals, so not the usual over-adding petals. In any case, it seems well done.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, from the shape of the leaves and the 4 petalled flowers, and the fact its more of a vine like plant, they've based this on Clematis montana var. grandiflora, info and image here https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/210221/i-clematis-montana-i-var-i-grandiflora-i-(m)/details. Artistic licence will have been used though - there are no stamens in the centre of these fake ones.

Comment: Or that. Good catch.

Comment: Artistic license also means this is also a bonsai version of the real thing, which will grow 30 feet high given half a chance!. https://twitter.com/landscapeman/status/1005417294271516674

Comment: yea - but if this was the real plant, this would just be one stem cut from the main plant